# XMLReader Invalid XML Character Exception

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I am parsing a big XML file ~500MB, and it contains some invalid XML character `0x07` , so you can imagine what's happening, the XMLReader is throwing an Invalid XML character exception, to handle this we streamed the `Stream` into `StreamReader` and used `Regex.Replace` and wrote the result to memory using `StreamWriter` and stream the clean version back to `XMLReader`, now I would like to avoid this and skip this filthy tag from the XMLReader directly, my question is if there's anyway to achieve that, below is the code snippet where I try to do this but it's throwing the exception at this line
`var node = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);`

```
        protected override IEnumerable<XElement> StreamReader(Stream stream, string elementName)
    {

        var arrTag = elementName.Split('|').ToList();
        using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false }))
        {
            while (xr.Read())
            {
                if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && arrTag.Contains(xr.Name))
                {
                    var node = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);
                    node.ReplaceWith(node.Elements().Where(e => e.Name != "DaylightSaveInfo"));
                    yield return node;
                }
            }
            xr.Close();
        }
 }
```

XML SAMPLE, the invalid attribute DaylightSaveInfo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<LATree>
<LA className="BTT00NE" fdn="NE=9739">
    <attr name="fdn">NE=9739</attr>
    <attr name="IP">10.157.144.100</attr>
    <attr name="realLatitude">0D0&apos;0&quot;S</attr>
    <attr name="realLongitude">0D0&apos;0&quot;W</attr>
    <attr name="DaylightSaveInfo">NO</attr>
</LA>
</LATree>
```

[image: BEL Character]

Comment: It is not invalid!!! See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @elias ghali  please always paste the  stack  trace it is useful for us to  understand the issue

Comment: @jdweng: An XML 1.0 document cannot include U+0007 even if it's specified as an entity reference. It would be valid to do that in XML 1.1.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : There are only 5 characters that are not valid xml. U+0007 is unicode 16 bits and this is 8 bits.  The ASCII 7 is the BELL character.  The sample xml data posted does not give any errors.

Comment: XML is UTF-8 by default. If you need a specific encoding then you have to specify it in the prolog.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] so we can help without guessing.

Comment: @jdweng: I'm afraid you're simply incorrect, and the part about 16 bits vs 8 bit is entirely irrelevant. I'm well aware of U+0007 being the bell character, but in XML 1.0, the only valid characters lower than U+0020 are tab, carriage return and line feed. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: This isn't about encodings - if the text contains a bell character, that's just invalid XML (1.0).

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: I suspect it'll be hard for the OP to include a bell character in a copy/pastable form. Although it's easy enough to construct a string with that in and then show that failing to parse.

Comment: If you're being provided with invalid XML, I would *start* by asking wherever you're getting that XML from to give you a valid XML document to start with. If they're supplying invalid data in that aspect, who knows what else is wrong...

Comment: Faulty backend code tends to do that a lot. You are right about the characters allowed in XML 1.0, I had forgot about the lower range.

Comment: This code  `var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><root>\a</root>"` reproduces the issue. You need to clean up your stream, there is no way around it.

Answer (score 2):

I just saw that Jon Skeet wrote something about this, so I cannot take credit really, but since his stature on SO is way above mine, I could perhaps gain a point or two for writing it. :)

First I wrote a class that overloads the TextReader class. 
(Some reference material in the links.)

https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char

https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/textreader.cs

```
class FilterInvalidXmlReader : System.IO.TextReader
{
  private System.IO.StreamReader _streamReader;

  public System.IO.Stream BaseStream => _streamReader.BaseStream;

  public FilterInvalidXmlReader(System.IO.Stream stream) => _streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);

  public override void Close() => _streamReader.Close();

  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) => _streamReader.Dispose();

  public override int Peek()
  {
    var peek = _streamReader.Peek();

    while (IsInvalid(peek, true))
    {
      _streamReader.Read();

      peek = _streamReader.Peek();
    }

    return peek;
  }

  public override int Read()
  {
    var read = _streamReader.Read();

    while (IsInvalid(read, true))
    {
      read = _streamReader.Read();
    }

    return read;
  }


  public static bool IsInvalid(int c, bool invalidateCompatibilityCharacters)
  {
    if (c == -1)
    {
      return false;
    }

    if (invalidateCompatibilityCharacters && ((c >= 0x7F && c <= 0x84) || (c >= 0x86 && c <= 0x9F) || (c >= 0xFDD0 && c <= 0xFDEF)))
    {
      return true;
    }

    if (c == 0x9 || c == 0xA || c == 0xD || (c >= 0x20 && c <= 0xD7FF) || (c >= 0xE000 && c <= 0xFFFD))
    {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Then I created a console application and in the main I put:

```
  using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<Test><GoodAttribute>a\u0009b</GoodAttribute><BadAttribute>c\u0007d</BadAttribute></Test>")))
  {
    using (var xmlFilteredTextReader = new FilterInvalidXmlReader(memoryStream))
    {
      using (var xr = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(xmlFilteredTextReader))
      {
        while (xr.Read())
        {
          if (xr.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element)
          {
            var xe = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.ReadFrom(xr);

            System.Console.WriteLine(xe.ToString());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Hopefully this could help, or at least provide some starter point.

Comment: Thank you @Rob for the effort, but again we already applied a similar approach to solve the issue, but the thing is that I was hoping to avoid the `TextReader` intervention and the Memory loading as we have big files ~500MB and sometimes bigger which also will be parsed in parallel with other files of similar size also and this will increase the Memory consumption drastically, so for now I'm stuck with this approach that I don't prefer

Comment: The MemoryStream was only used to provide a working example for the XML string example. You can use a file stream directly to your 500 MB file instead of the memory stream. All that my reader is doing is removing characters as the stream is passing through.

Comment: I see your point thank you for the insight, though I believe there's a trade off here between memory consumption and parsing performance

Answer (score -2):

Following xml linq code runs without errors.  I used in xml file following "NO" :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.CheckCharacters = false;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("attr")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It only runs without errors if test.xml doesn't contain a bell character. If it *does* contain a bell character (e.g. added via a binary file editor) you'll get an exception of Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: '', hexadecimal value 0x07, is an invalid character. Line 8, position 27. (Obviously the reported position depends on where the bell character is within the file.)

Comment: If you change the document loading with `XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><root>\a</root>");` you'll get the actual error.

Comment: I was finally able to duplicate error by using NO&#07;&#07; for BELL.  Then fixed by  setting CheckCharacters to false.

Comment: @jdweng, please go back to my question I already set CheckCharacters  to false, but it fails on `var node = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(xr);` , I even tried `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xr);` and also it raises the same exception

Comment: I know that.  The character must be something else.  Try doing following with actual bad data and check character codes :            string input = "NO\a\a";
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input).Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng: "The character must be something else" - what makes you think that? I can reproduce the exact error reported here, using the XML and code shown. As far as I can tell, `XmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters` doesn't help when the character is directly in the XML rather than specified as an entity.

Comment: I can repeat also.  And then use CheckCharacter equals false and it works.  I did not try with unicode 7 I used "NO&#07;&#07;".

Comment: Please read the end of my previous comment: "XmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters doesn't help when the character is directly in the XML rather than specified as an entity". So testing it *using an entity* would indeed be fine, but putting the invalid character directly in the XML isn't. And that's the situation the OP is facing. With the character directly in the XML file, setting CheckCharacter to false **does not help**.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes exactly that's the issue i'm facing thank you

Comment: @EliasGhali: Unfortunately my conclusion is the same as Leonardo's - you either need to fix the XML first, or better, get the provider to fix the code that's creating the invalid XML. You *could* potentially write a `TextReader` implementation that delegates to another `TextReader` and checks for invalid characters, replacing them with something else, when they're being read. But if possible, I'd suggest putting the XML through a separate preprocessing phase, outside the application itself. It's hard to give more specific advice without knowing more context unfortunately.

Comment: @JonSkeet your observation is very specific actually, basically it's an ETL process, and yes maybe this should be handled in a previous phase maybe during mediation,  I was hoping maybe XMLReader has some method that allows me to simply skip the <attr name="DaylightSaveInfo"> tag before loading it and looping over the nodes maybe this would have solved it, but seems this is not provided, thank you

Comment: As fix all that has to be done is replace "\a" with an empty string or "#07;"

Comment: @jdweng: The whole point of the question is to *avoid* having to clean up the file. The OP knows how to do the cleanup, but they're trying to find a solution that doesn't need it.